# My bottom navigation view is being overwritten with my ListView Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

My bottom navigation view which is displayed behind the listview allows users to press a button to add a new item to the list view. Is there a way to bring the element at the bottom of the page (bottom_navigation_view) to the front? Into view over the ListView

My code looks like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCategories"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
        android:divider="@color/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/primary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change Your ListView layout parameters to:

```
  <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
        android:divider="@color/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip" />
```